# General technique for loss function minimization

Tags: self-study, k-means

I was trying to rationalize the K-Means algorithm and came up with the following thoughts.

Suppose we need to compute:

$T=min_x L(x)$

but we struggle because $L$ is complex. Suppose we find $L'$ s.t.:

$min_y L'(x,y)= L(x)$

SIDE NOTE: note that this framework defines a function $y=y(x)$ where the minimum is attained, that may be etiher easy or difficult to calculate, but in both cases we may get an improved formulation. We have $L'(x,y(x))=L(x)$ and $L'(x,y)\ge L(x)$ if $y \ne y(x)$.

If this is the case than we can evaluate $T$ as:

$T=min_{x,y} L'(x,y)$

So **we have rewritten the minimum of $L(x)$ as a minimum of an extended function $L'(x,y)$**. It may be that :

1. $L'$ is easier to minimize either via block descent than direct $L$ minimization. E.g. it may be easier to minimize $L'$ at fixed $y$ rather than $L$ directly. In one case we may get an analytical solution for example, but not in the other. Further, the loss function may be highly non-convex for $L(x)$ but convex for $L'$ at fixed $y$.
2. The partial derivatives of $L'$, in a differential setting, could be easier to evaluate than the ones of $L$.

E.g. I think the general framework applies to K-Means where $x$ are the label assignemts and $y$ the cluster centers.

My question:

- Do the trick and thoughts make sense?
- Are there more general principles underlying this technique?
- What are some application examples to develop more the intuition?

I hope the question is not too unclear, it is more brainstorming to develop intution about algorithms...

Comment: If you minimize $L'$ with respect to both $x$ and $y$, then the minimizer $(x^\ast, y^\ast)$ will a priori not satisfy $y^\ast=y(x^\ast)$.

Comment: Mmm if I minimize $L'$ and I am able to get a minimum $T$ at $(x^*, y^*)$, in particular fixing $x^*$ the function $f(y)=L'(x^*,y)$ should get a minimum at $y=y^*$ (otherwise we would have found a point below $T$), so that using our notation $y^*=y(x^*)$... even if I am not sure why this is central..

Comment: you might want to look at Expectation-Maximisation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm

Comment: you are right. I have to check it more but at least some aspects of the EM algorithm seems to fall under this general idea... even if I wonder when the EM algorithm will stop creating me an headache when I think about it :D